# Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. If the subsequence $a_{2^n}$ converges , then $a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or disprove: Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. If the subsequence $a_{2^n}$ converges , then $a_n$ converges.

What I tried:
$a_{2^n}$ converges so $\lvert a_{2^p}-l\rvert\lt\varepsilon_1$ for $p\gt
N_{\varepsilon_1},\varepsilon_1 \gt 0 $. I want to show that $\lvert a_{r}-l\rvert\lt\varepsilon_2$ for $r \gt N_{\varepsilon_2} $.
So $\lvert a_{r}-l\rvert\lt\lvert a_{q}-a_{2^p}+a_{2^p}-l\rvert \lt \lvert a_{r}-a_{2^p}\rvert+\lvert a_{2^p}-l\rvert\lt\lvert a_{r}-a_{2^p}\rvert+\varepsilon_1$.

Here I got stuck, I can't find a relationship between the two.

How can I prove or disprove the statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement is wrong.

Counterexample:

$a_{n}=\begin{cases} \frac1n,\,\text{if $n=2^k$}\\ n,\,\text{else}\end{cases}$

The subsequence $(a_{2^n})$ converges to $0$, but $(a_n)$ does not converge.

Comment: A simpler way to disprove this similarly is just $$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac1n&n\text{ even}\\n&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think 'simpler' is subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Comman example is fine, yet I want to highlight that the non convergence is not always due to having another subsequence which is divergent.

The main point is that it is possible to have two adherent values.

For instance $\begin{cases} a_{2^n}=1\\a_n = 0 &\text{else.}\end{cases}$

Even though both "parts" converge, the whole sequence is not convergent.